# Flow: Getting error when using Map

Tags: javascript, flowtype, static-typing

I have just started to implement type checking using Facebook Flow in one of my projects, and have encountered some issues. I am trying to do the following with a Map:

```
/* @flow */

let testMap: Map<string, Array<number>> = new Map();
let key: string = "testString";

if (!testMap.has(key)) {
  testMap.set(key, [])
}

testMap.get(key).push(1);
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
Cannot call `testMap.get(...).push` because property `push` is missing in undefined [1]
```

Se example in try flow:
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVMCmAXM3MDO2AsgIYAOAXGGeQDxEBOAlgHYDmANGAIKOOkAnnVYBXALYAjTIwB8ssAF4wrTEloAKAJQBuDDjABrTIOpM27JWABE+IgGVsLDtb2pmUMBoCEdkhQA6AAtSAg1jQS0tMABvVDA8Qn9yAIIccJNuAG0AXS1UAF90P1oA9nSIrQDyUQIgjQBGXVQgA

This is of course because the get function in the Map interface is defined as:

```
get(key: K): V | void;
```

But I was expecting Flow to recognize that the key is actually being set just above.

Any suggestions on how I should change my code in order to make Flow happy?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, the problem here is that your call to `Map.get` may return `void` as you can see in `V | void`.

Flow has no chance to know whether your key was defined or not as this may change during runtime.

Thus you need to check whether the returned value is not `undefined` before accessing it's `push` method.

```
const arr = testMap.get(key);

if (arr) {
  arr.push(1)
} else {
  // map "testMap" didn't contain a value for key "key"
}
```

full demo in flow repl: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVMCmAXM3MDO2AsgIYAOAXGGeQDxEBOAlgHYDmANGAIKOOkAnnVYBXALYAjTIwB8ssAF4wrTEloAKAJQBuDDjABrTIOpM27JWABE+IgGVsLDtb2pmUMBoCEdkhQA6AAtSAg1jQS0tMABvVDA8Qn9yAIIccJNuAG0AXS1UAF90AGM4ViIwUn4rP1oA9nSI3XQPLyrGaLiE9oDyUQIgjQBGfIKwTBg02PiwYGAwcQobWoprMAATZnXWAHJcUtZsUjZKsAA3UhhRTDAoOEYjExsI60KgA

---

Another approach would be like this:

```
let arr = testMap.get(key);

if (!arr) {
  arr = [];
  testMap.set(key, arr);
}

arr.push(1);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that because Flow is a static checker, it has limited ability to tell what can happen at runtime.  Requirement Invalidations in the docs explains the concept, even if Flow knew that `has` was a valid accessor, the state of the map might have changed by the time of the `get`.  As this answer outlines, the solution is to record the return value and remove the ambiguity.